# framer motion is not transitioning when switched between keyframe animations

Tags: javascript, reactjs, animation, framer-motion

I have 2 keyframe animation variants and when I switch between them I want it to happen with the transition. How can I make it transition all the props when switched from one keyframe animation to another (currently it happens instantly)?

```js
const variants = {
  ...,
  horizontalWiggle: {
    x: ["40px", "80px"],
    y: [0, 0],
    transition: { duration: 0.5, yoyo: Infinity }
  },
  verticalWiggle: {
    x: [0, 0],
    y: ["8px", "40px"],
    transition: { duration: 0.5, yoyo: Infinity }
  }
}
```

Using with framer motion as so:

```js
<motion.div
 className="wiggle"
 variants={variations}
 initial="init"
 animate={vertical ? "verticalWiggle" : "horizontalWiggle"}
/>
```

Link to the sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/long-surf-405lho?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 2):

You have two options:

1. You should not specify `0` for axis which you do not want to animate. That way there will be no instant jump and will be smooth animation between variants.
2. The idea is **start** new animation (new variant) from **last** position of previous variant. Another words: you need to **stop old** animation and **start new** animation from the same value (the same keyframe). That way there also will be no instant jump.

Full example here: [image: Edit festive-driscoll-m8wx9j]

**NOTE:** if you need to animate between variants - you could create one more variant with animation from STATE-1 to STATE-2.
Like here: [image: Edit nifty-smoke-07efe6]

Short Example:

```js
const variations = {
  ...
  horizontalWiggle: {
    x: [0, 40, 80, 0],
    transition: { duration: 1, repeat: Infinity }
  },
  verticalWiggle: {
    y: ["0px", "20px", "40px", "0px"],
    transition: { duration: 1, repeat: Infinity }
  }
};
```